# Python 3 tkinter on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

Been fighting with this for too long wondered is someone might point me in the right direction.  I am trying to establish an App that when triggered by a pir sensor attached to the rasberry pi opens a Frame with 7 buttons on it.  I want the buttons when pressed to open separate frames in which i want to attach an image. I want the frame to disappear after a given time.

Now i can do this on the start page no problem creating a frame and canvas and loading an image in and then using after with destroy to get rid of it after 7 seconds.

However as soon as i try to bring other frames into the equation i cant seem to get canvases or images to work in the secondary frames. I changed my current approach which i set into clases (care of a tutorial on line) but dead end there as well.

Im not sure but i have the feeling that with classes i have now set up a master slave relationship with the frames meaning i cant customise them individually? I have attached the code im currently playing with that relates to the frames. If someone can advice be much appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(100, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(100, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour, PageFive, PageSix, PageSeven):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="SMART BIN Tech", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="NO DRINKS or FOOD WASTE",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="NO PAPER WASTE",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="NO TEA BAGS",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        button3.pack()

        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="NO CANS or PLASTICS",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageFour))
        button4.pack()

        button5 = tk.Button(self, text="LIST of RECYCLABLES",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageFive))
        button5.pack()

        button6 = tk.Button(self, text="Vending Area Performance",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSix))
        button6.pack()

        button7 = tk.Button(self, text="UBS UK RATIO",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSeven))
        button7.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="NO DRINKS or FOOD WASTE", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="NO PAPER WASTE", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()


class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="NO TEA BAGS", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

class PageFour(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="NO CANS or PLASTICS", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

class PageFive(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="RECYCLABLES", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

class PageSix(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Vending Area Performance", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        w = tk.Canvas(self,width=400,height=500)
        w.pack
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

class PageSeven(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="UBS UK RATIO", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self,width=100, height=100)
        canvas.pack
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid(row=2, column=5)
        button1.pack()


app = SeaofBTCapp()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have several issues right off the bat, you cannot mix grid and pack geometry managers inside the same container which you appear to be doing in page 7, you are also not actually calling pack in several places because you missed the brackets. once I correct these minor issues your app appears to work fine.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. If the problem is on one page, we don't need the code for all of the other pages -- one or two pages is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. much appreciated.  Apologies i added way to much.